# How to select all rows where cells are blank (and not just select the blank cells)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very large data set and want to remove all entries where not all information is filled out. In order to do this, I need to select all the rows where there are blank cells and delete them.

I only know how to select blank cells. If I press the delete button, I get this:

[image]

The cells collapse, and I get the wrong information for each cell.

I'd like to be able to do the following so that I can remove the blank entries altogether.

[image]

How can I do this on a very large scale (thousands of entries)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by applying a filter.

What you want to do is the following: Go to `Data` > `Filter`

You will see that at the top of each column, a dropdown box now is shown.

For each column, press the little arrow next to the column name, and set it to contains data. Repeat this for all colums.

Keep in mind that filtering on more columns will merge all filters together.

The result should be what you want to achieve in the end if you had deleted all empty cells.

You can still view everything by clearing the filter, or you can choose to copy what you have now to a new sheet to actually get rid of all empty cells.

Keep in mind, if you were to select, only empty cells per column, it will only show you empty rows because all filters are applied to the end result and you basically say: only show me empty rows then.

Comment: I appreciate it! I found a faster way to this in the long run on this page (http://pakaccountants.com/select-entire-rows-of-multiple-selected-cells-vba-macros/). It's a VBA command. I saved it to a hotkey and whenever I select one cell it selects the entire row. Very practical!

Comment: @AlexandredelaTour feel free to post an answer yourself. In 2 days you can mark that answer as solved so everyone knows you don't need any more help. If my answer was at least a bit helpful, consider giving it a thumbs up to show your appreciation.